# Dual boot wrong time on windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot

I had my Windows 10 installation, but then I decided to dual boot with Linux. I did it, and I noticed, that I have -2h on the clock on my Linux. I've searched the internet for the answer (the time zone was good). I don't really remember what I did, but I do remember setting `ntp` to true and `hwlclock systohc --rtc`, or something like this.

Now the time on my Linux is good, but the time on Windows is 2 hours late. I have to manually go to Adjust date/time -> Sync now to make it right.

I know this is messy, but I can't quite remember what exactly I did on Linux. Now the situation is like this. Is there a way to fix it? Or maybe force Windows to automatically sync, or something?

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple ways to do this as per:

> Source:
>   https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot

What I'd prefer and have done is executing this command on Linux: `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`

Answer (score 0):

Windows an Linux handle time differently, so interpret differently the
setting of hardware clock.

While Linux stores the time on the hardware clock as UTC by default,
Windows stores the time on the hardware clock as the 'local' time.

The simplest solution would be to have both use a time server
to update the hardware clock after booting.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, with NTP enabled on Linux, and "automatic time" on Windows, the time is still always wrong on Windows when rebooting. In Linux it works fine, I guess NTP does a good job. Disabling and enabling the automatic time "fixes" it. Slightly infuriating.

Comment: @bogdan.mustiata make sure to do "Sync now" after enabling "set time automatically" in windows.

Comment: @SaurabhMahra, even if it's with set time automatically, on reboot I always have to do it manually each time.